# Spring Cloud Stream configurationwith XML file instead of annotations

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream.

I don't like the approach of interfaces annotated with @Input or @Ouput and then use @EnableBindings of that interface because I have a lot of configuration stuff spreaded in my code.

Is there any way to configure that using XML configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *"because I have a lot of configuration stuff spread in my code"* is not really a question of XML vs. Annotation. If one is not careful with their design it doesn't matter what approach you take, you will have a mess. So basically it's not a valid reason and/or concern, rather personal preference.

There are way to use XML in your spring-cloud-stream application; After all the actual application is really a Spring Integration(SI) app that receives and/or send from/to Message channels. 
However, with regard to `@EnableBindings, @Input or @Ouput` one must understand their core purpose(s) which are:

- to create and bind SI channels to resources (queue, topic) exposed by the binders
- to assist with provisioning of such resources (queue, topic)

  etc. . .

Of course you can take care of it yourself by falling back on pure SI and use inbound/outbound adapters, connection and session factories, retry templates etc..., but that would not constitute a spring-cloud-stream app.

Also, don't forget about Spring Boot where lot's of the stuff is created based on convention/opinion, where you don't need to do anything at all (other then having an auto-config JAR in your classpath) and spring-cloud-stream really builds on these concepts by only requiring you to provide a single configuration element out of the box - `@EnableBindings` and we take care of the rest.

So in reality the question is really *to boot or not to boot* - not XML vs Annotation.

Having said that, we are constantly exploring options where configuration could be simplified, so if you have suggestions please share.